# How do you create a request which is authenticated with kerberos in Rust

Tags: rust, request, kerberos

I'm "relatively new" to rust and am trying to solve more complicated tasks. Sadly I have not been able authenticate with a kerberos enabled endpoint yet. I have tried / experimented with most kerberos crates but couldn't find a solution myself yet. I have also tried curl implementations to no avail.

I have a host which is authenticated with kerberos (TGTs are listed when using klist) and I'm trying to create a request to a kerberos secured website / endpoint (get/post). I don't have any specific requirement how the request is created / which crate is used to handle requests, as long as they are authenticated.

I have previously worked with python and handled requests with a module for kerberos. Is there any similar crate or implementation which would allow me not authenticate "easily" similarly to the kerberos-request python module?

E.g. `requests.get("http://example.org", auth=HTTPKerberosAuth())` in python.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any "easy to use" libraries, but here's the general approach if you want to make your own:

1. Find a library that provides either bindings to the system's GSSAPI library (for Linux) or to the system's SSPI library (for Windows). Yes, you do want the system libraries, especially for Windows – it's how you gain access to credentials the system has stored for you.

   - https://github.com/estokes/libgssapi
   - https://crates.io/crates/gssapi
   - maybe https://github.com/Devolutions/sspi-rs (not sure if it provides access to the system's SSPI credentials)
2. Before making a request: Call the GSSAPI "initialize context" function, providing the correct server SPN, and specifying 'initiate' as the mode and 'SPNEGO' as the mechanism.

   There are two "name types" that can be used; one is the GSSAPI hostbased_name and the other is Kerberos principal name. Generally GSSAPI will expect the former (hostbased_name) type; for HTTP it will be `HTTP@` (uppercase) + the exact domain specified in the URL (lowercase). The Kerberos principal name is similar but with `HTTP/`.
3. Call the "step" function on the context to receive a token.
4. Base64-encode the token, format it as `Negotiate <token>` (e.g. "Negotiate AbCd"), then add it as an `Authorization:` header to your request.
5. The HTTP response might give you another token in WWW-Authenticate, which you can provide to the step() function for "mutual auth", but in practice it's safe to ignore – I believe requests-kerberos doesn't do mutual auth by default either, it just relies on TLS to authenticate the server.

Because HTTP is stateless and doesn't persist auth, *each* new request will need you to create a *new* GSSAPI context so that it would start again from step 1. (Note that "new request" includes followed redirects, too – tokens are *not* reusable – so you'll need to hook into the HTTP client so that it does all of this automatically.)